# How to get the data using foreignkey in hibernate envers?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

i have Two entities where student with address manytoone relationship.In student i have used the following snippet in my example.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_NR", nullable=false)
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED) 
public Address getStudentAddress() {
 return this.studentAddress;
}
```

now i am trying to get the history table data using ADDRESS_NR, than i am getting error like as follows

and the retrival codesnippet is

```
List personHistory = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager)
    .createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(Student.class, false, true)
    .add(AuditEntity.property("ADDRESS_NR")
    .eq(id))
    .getResultList();
```

and the error is as follows

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: ADDRESS_NR of: com.audit.test.Student_AUD [select e__, r from com.audit.test.Student_AUD e__, com.audit.test.AuditRevisionEntity r where e__.ADDRESS_NR = :_p0 and e__.originalId.REV.id = r.id order by e__.originalId.REV.id asc]"

Can some one help me?

Comment: Did you check whether a generated schema STUDENT_AUD contains the ADDRESS_NR column?

Comment: SELECT * FROM STUDENT ;
STUDENT_ID   STUDENT_AGE   STUDENT_NAME   ADDRESS_NR  
1 12 Eswar2 2
(1 row, 1 ms)

SELECT * FROM STUDENT_AUD ;
STUDENT_ID   REV   REVTYPE   STUDENT_AGE   STUDENT_NAME   ADDRESS_NR  
1 3 0 1 Eswar2 2
1 4 1 11 Eswar2 2
1 5 1 12 Eswar2 2
(3 rows, 0 ms)

SELECT * FROM ADDRESS ;
ADDRESS_ID   ADDRESS_CITY   ADDRESS_STATE   ADDRESS_STREET   ADDRESS_ZIPCODE  
2 Chennai TN OMR Road 600099

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, its important to understand the distinction between column and property.

Whenever you use the `AuditProperty#property(String)` method, you're asking Envers to resolve an object model property to a column mapping, so you want to be sure that you provide the property name rather than the explicit column name as your code snippet.

In other words, I would expect your code to be doing the following:

```
List personHistory = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager)
  .createQuery()
  .forRevisionsOfEntity(Student.class, false, true)
  .traverseRelation("studentAddress", JoinType.LEFT, "address")
  .up()
  .add(AuditEntity.relatedId("studentAddress").eq(id))
  .getResultList();
```

I included the `traverseRelation` method call here to illustrate how you could add additional predicates on the `Address` relation if needed by including those prior to the call to `up()` as they'll be predicates based on the join-table associated with `Address`.